# Conditionally render anchor link around div in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a component which is wrapped in an anchor link and has hover styling. I need to be able to conditionally render the `channel.url` link on the div if there is an available url in the data for the particular element that has been looped through.

I tried checking if the length of the `channel.url` is greater than 0, but my logic wasn't working. In the end, it should simply be that if the particular item that's looped through doesn't have a url in its data object, it will simply not have the anchor link applied to it.

```
  <ul>
    {items.children.map((channel, i) => (
      (channel, i) =>
            channel.url ? (
              <a href={channel.url} target="_blank">
                <FeaturedApps />
              </a>
            ) : (
              <FeaturedApps />
            )
        )}
    ))}
  </ul>
```

**UPDATE**

I got the logic working, thanks to Ethan. Trying to clean it up thought and move the li to its own component but having an issue passing `icon` in.

**COMPONENT**

```
const FeaturedApps = ({ iconName, className }) => {
  <li>
    <IconForChannel iconName={channel.icon} className={classes.icon} />
    <span className={classes.channelName}>
      {channel.name}{" "}
      <Icon className={classes.nameIcon} name={channel.nameicon} size={12} />
    </span>
  </li>;
};
```

**LOOP WITH LOGIC**

```
 <ul>
    {items.children.map((channel, i) => (
      (channel, i) =>
            channel.url ? (
              <a href={channel.url} target="_blank">
                <FeaturedApps />
              </a>
            ) : (
              <FeaturedApps />
            )
        )}
    ))}
  </ul>
```

Comment: `React` or not you should only put `li`s as a children of `ul`. "Permitted content zero or more <li> elements, which in turn often contain nested <ol> or <ul> elements."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work:

```
  <ul>
    {items.children.map((channel, i) => (
      (channel.url) ?
      <a href={channel.url} target="_blank">
        <li key={i}>
          <span className={classes.channelName}>
            {channel.name}
          </span>
        </li>
      </a>
      :
      <li key={i}>
        <span className={classes.channelName}>
          {channel.name}
        </span>
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
```

This ternary operator is saying: "for each channel, if that channel has a url as a property, render that list item wrapped in the channel.url as an anchor link, else, simply render the list item."

condition ? expr1 : expr2

Comment: This is a good solution and works. However, I'm trying to pull the `li` element into its own component, but getting an issue with the icon in `<Icon />` not being passed in.

Comment: Hi @Matt, glad I was able to help with this problem! Please mark my answer as correct if it was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Will do, Ethan. Any ideas on the additional issue I posted above? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, not sure about the icons. You may want to ask a separate question for that!

Comment: Perhaps your FeaturedApps component needs to be passed icon as props?

Comment: For example:

`<FeaturedApps 
  icon={channel.icon}
/>`

Then in your FeaturedApps component:

`const FeaturedApps = ({ iconName, className }) => {
  <li>
    <IconForChannel iconName={props.icon}  />
       //etc.
  </li>;
};`

Answer (score 0):

You could save the 'inner' part to a variable and render conditionally, i.e.

```
<ul>
  {items.children.map((channel, i) => {
    let inner = (<span className={classes.channelName}>
      {channel.name}
    </span>);
    return (
      <li key={i}>
        { (channel.url ? (<a href={channel.url} target="_blank">{inner}</a>) : inner) }
      </li>
    </a>
    )};
  )}
</ul>
```

it was mentioned above that li should always be the direct child of ul, and I've adjusted that also while at it. Hope this is helpful.